# How to write devexpress combo box change event in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

i have devexpress combo box in my form , i want to write some script on change in angular,
but am not getting change event in of combo in angular, am able to get in javascript

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
    <div>
      @Html.DevExpress().FormLayout(settings => { 
          GeneralFormTypesAPI _gftAPI = new GeneralFormTypesAPI();     
          settings.Name = "FormLayout1"; 
          settings.ColCount = 2; 
          settings.Items.Add(i => { 
              i.Caption = "Form Type"; 
              i.NestedExtensionType = FormLayoutNestedExtensionItemType.ComboBox;
              i.NestedExtensionSettings.Name = "formTypeCB"; 
              ComboBoxSettings combo = (ComboBoxSettings)i.NestedExtensionSettings; 
              combo.SelectedIndex = 0; 
              combo.Properties.ValueType = typeof(string); 
              combo.Properties.TextField = "TypeName"; 
              combo.Properties.ValueField = "ID"; 
              combo.Properties.DataSource = _gftAPI.GetGeneralFormTypeCB();          
              combo.Properties.EnableClientSideAPI = true; 
              combo.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function(s, e){HideGridviewColumn(s,e)}"; 
          }); 
       }).GetHtml()
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

HideGridviewColumn event working in normal javascript , but i want call this event from angular

javascript

```
<script>
    function HideGridviewColumn(s, e) {
       alert('am in');//am getting alert here
    }
</script>
```

angular

```
$scope.HideGridviewColumn= function () {
   alert('sss');//am not getting alert here
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: You need to have a angular's `ng-change` event.

Comment: yes Jai for devexpress combo box

Comment: is it possible to write ng-change event in devexpress combo box